# Why does ipv6 not specify a protocol version?

Tags: ip, ipv6, ipv4, network-protocols

I am relatively new to dealing with network packets, but as I look into the ipv6 header formats, I do not see a place where the ipv6 headers define what protocol is used in the data section -- but the ipv4 protocol does.

Am I missing where ipv6 gives the protocol information, or is that information no longer deemed necessary?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the "Next Header" field in IPv6 does the same thing as the "Protocol" field does in IPv4. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers .

Answer (score 0):

The version (= 6) in IPv6 is located in the exact same place in the packet that it is in IPv4: the first 4 bits. That way, you can read the first 4 bits of the packet and find out  which version of IP the packet is without knowing in advance.

Comment: That's not quite the field I was talking about. I'm not talking about which version of the IP protocol being used. In IPv4 there is a ["protocol" field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Protocol) at byte 9. For example, it could be the value of 6 which would mean that the data itself is using TCP.

Comment: I see what you were looking for now, but this Answer is correct given what the Question seems to be asking for...

Comment: Ah yes, I see I misunderstood what you were asking! But yeah, you seem to have got the answer you were looking for, regarding the next header field.